# Perl: CPAN - Module modifying and adding functionality

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I find a module, that I want to change.

My problem have some features like this:

- I want to **add functionality and flexibility** to this module.
- Now this module solves tasks, but web-service, for what it was written, change API
- And also, I want to use code of this module.
- It is **not** my module
- Fix some bugs

How i should be in this situation?

- Inheriting from this module and add functionality and upload to CPAN?
- Ask author about my modifications (and reload module)?
- Something else?

Comment: Can you tell us which module it is?

Comment: VK module (https://metacpan.org/module/VK)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various ways to modify a module as you use it, and I cover most of them in [Mastering Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527242.do).

- As [Dave Cross mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11699686/8817), send fixes upstream or become part of that project. It sounds like you have the ambition to be a significant contributor. :)
- Create a subclass to replace methods
- Override or overload subroutines or methods
- Wrap subroutines to modify or adapt either inputs or outputs (e.g. [Hook::LexWrap](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Hook::LexWrap))
- Create a locally patched version, and store it separately from the main code so it doesn't disappear in an upgrade

For example, this is something I often do directly in program code while I wait for an upstream fix:

```
use Some::Module;  # load the original first
BEGIN {
   package Some::Module;
   no warnings 'redefine';
   if( $VERSION > 1.23 and $VERSION < 1.45 ) {
     *broken = sub { ... fixed version ... };
     }
   }
```

This way, I have the fix even if the target module is upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your a and b options are pretty much the best approach - although I'd probably do them the other way round.

1. Approach the module author with your suggestions. Read the module
   documentation to find out how the author likes to be contacted. Some
   like email, some like [RT](http://rt.cpan.org/), other have more specific methods.
   Authors tend to like suggestions better if they come with tests for
   the new/changed code and patches that can be applied freely. Perhaps
   the code is on Github. Can you fork it, make your changes and send
   the author a pull request?
2. If the author is unresponsive, then consider either forking or
   subclassing their code. In this case, naming is important as you
   want people to be able to find your module as well as the original
   one. You'll also want to carefully document the differences between
   your version and the original one so that people can choose which
   one they want.