# How to use CPAN modules without access to CPAN?

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I am greatly disappointed every time I am forced to retrieve a module from CPAN.  In most environments I work in, internet access is severely restricted or completely denied.  All compilers have been removed during the OS hardening process.  And all digital storage media is scanned by a security team before entering or exiting the site.  Mind you, I understand security, and all of this is OK with me, but...

What is the recommended or best practice for accessing code only CPAN modules provide.

If I only need a snippet, a function, or a single string of functionality a module gives me, how can I extract "just what I need/want" without installing an entire module?  Keeping in mind that I may be literally printing out, writing down, and typing in, to transfer the data from an off-site location with internet access.

Comment: Have you asked your boss or security? It may be they have a policy, or are willing to create one. (For example, they might be willing to pre-clear some modules and set them up within the secure area, esp. if you aren't the only one who could make use of it.) My experience is if I'm having a problem, I'm probably not the first, and the powers that be may have a solution from the last time - even if they're initially reluctant to dust it off again.

Comment: I do write code because I am lazy.  I prefer NOT to type the same command every time I need to do the same or similar things.  I asked my question here, because I have exhausted all my options in the work environment to achieve the task of accessing CPAN.  I do appreciate your response, and valid points, but I have already been down this path.

Comment: You didn't actually mention what you'd tried. I've worked in facilities where an armed guard had to sit next to me, but, if the pain point was high enough, a process could be found - not always though (my experience was during the end of the Cold War, so security flexibility often changed by the week).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you can't access CPAN - how you want use it? So, you can either:

- when have internet access - you can install modules
- if havent, you can bring an `minicpan` on USB stick or soo
- if this is not possible because security policy, you can only use e.g. you mobile phone to show source on CPAN and retype the needed parts manually
- if neither is possible - you can at home print the source code on your tshirt and retype it in the work :)
- or, simply must programm all things yourself - by learning at home
- or, find the better job :)

EDIT: More serious approach

First, it is strange to have an company who developing with perl, but doesn't allow use CPAN. Of course, I understand than direct access to a tons of unscanned sw is not acceptable for many companies, but in this case here should be exists some "company policies" - how to allow access.

Here are several questions:

- the hardening is at technical level only (firewalls etc) - so you can bring e.g. USB stick, CD or any other medium inside, or
- policy level - the policy does not allow using any external source

If it is at policy level - IMHO, you're out of luck. Simply when it is NOT ALLOWED using any external source - you can use really only the "print & retype" method.

Here is some possibilities:

### establish an company-wide local CPAN repository

Create an local CPAN ([minicpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini/bin/minicpan)) server with "trusted" modules. This repository can function as repository for locally developed modules too.  In this case must exists some "auditing authority" (policies & procedures) how to get modules into the local repo. IMHO, this can be the most useful way - when the company using perl on regular basis.

Of course, mixing system-wide (default perl modules) with CPAN modules not the best idea. Therefore is possible to setup:

### local::lib or build-prefix

[local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm) - create and use a local lib/ for perl modules with PERL5LIB. Google for `perl "local::lib"` or something similar. Also read some other SQ questions:

- [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)
- [How can I use a new Perl module without install permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions)
- [How can I install CPAN modules locally without root access (DynaLoader.pm line 229 error)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102850/how-can-i-install-cpan-modules-locally-without-root-access-dynaloader-pm-line-2)
- and other

Using local::lib is nice solution, because doesn't break system-wide perl modules. Of course, again - you will need some "auditing process" how to get modules *inside*.

### perlbrew

Using your own built perl - [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) - is more general solution if the system hasn't installed perl. You don't need root access for building your own perl. Of course, here is still some problems (besides the auditing), e.g. the "missing compiler problem".

### virtual machine

You can try setup an virtual machine for development (or isolated physical machine) with full CPAN access and develop here. When you finish the development, you can forward your work with all required modules to "auditing process".

### other

If you need only extract an function or a modules from the CPAN modules, do it on external machine. Extracting a function or some part is not a technical problem (when you know perl) it is more an license problem - using a part of modules in your work - you need cite the author.

For this you need fetch all needed functions - can find interesting this [discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=798738). Google for "perl functions dependencies" or something similar, or:

- [How can I determine CPAN dependencies before I deploy a Perl project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240704/how-can-i-determine-cpan-dependencies-before-i-deploy-a-perl-project)
- http://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Extract::Use
- http://metacpan.org/pod/Module::ScanDeps
- [Perl: CPAN - Module modifying and adding functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699118/perl-cpan-module-modifying-and-adding-functionality?rq=1)

Maybe, you will find [this discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=514420) interesting too...

Comment: In this environment, they probably aren't going to allow him to download or a gig of unscanned and unevaluated software to have inside the secure facility.

Comment: I almost never had access to cpan in org's using direct install. Org's(mostly) block these ports for security reasons. Using manual install you can get pass through it.

Comment: I do appreciate the responses, and valid points, but I have already been down this path.  I have worked in many "hardened" environments, and occasionally I get lucky when requesting special access, but most times I do not.  There is also reluctance to update/upgrade perl core in order to use a module.  I was hoping others with similar experiences could share solutions, work arounds and ideas.